# Paypal as deposit

Tags: android, paypal

I´ve seen the news pass by that they want to ban other payments in the Android Market (Google Play), so also because of that, my question is can I integrate PayPal in an Market-app and can I use Paypal as a creditcard processor for a deposit.

So block € 100,-, which I return after a few hours..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can, yes. Whether or not you'll get removed from Google Play or not is a different question. According to [some articles](http://www.mercurynews.com/top-stories/ci_20131998) there are developers who were told explicitly not to use PayPal but to use Google Wallet or face removal from the market.